# Markdown typographical features or Unicode glyphs?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

Which are the pros and cons of depending on Markdown support for typographical features after ASCII characters (like `--`, `---` and `...` for en- and em-dashes and ellipsis) vs. using the Unicode glyphs themselves (­–, — and …) in the text?

[I am considering writing dynamic reports in rmarkdown that can be converted (knitr+pandoc) to html, pdf and docx/odt formats.

Answer (score 0):

Some editors that aren't compatible with Unicode will mangle Unicode glyphs.  It's more common in older or poorly written text editors. I've seen characters removed directly, or replaced with garbage depending on the editor.  If all editors used to manage your markdown, as well as the parsers you use to process your markdown, are compatible with Unicode, then there may be no downside to using those glyphs directly.